# Matrix representation of the Quaternions?

Tags: matrices, quaternions

Can anyone explain how why [the matrix representation of the quaternions using real matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Matrix_representations) is constructed as such?

Comment: Maybe helpful: Think of the Quaternions as a four dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ with basis ${1,i,j,k}$. Then think of the natural action of the Quatenions on this vector space. The matrices you get for the actions of $1,i,j,k$ are just the ones you found in Wikipedia.

Comment: Could you explain what a natural action is? I'm unfamiliar with the term.

Comment: The action of multiplication. Let's take the case of multiplication by $i$ on the left ($x\mapsto ix$). This is a linear action on this vector space, so it can be represented by a matrix relative to the basis ${1,i,j,k}$. Find this matrix.

Comment: @user3533: How do you convert a linear action into a matrix?

Comment: The usual way you represent a linear operator as a matrix. In the first column put the coefficients of $i \cdot 1 = i$, in the second column, those of $i \cdot i = -1$, in the third those of $i \cdot j = k$ and in the forth those of $i \cdot k = -j$

Comment: (the coefficients of $a1+bi+cj+dk$ are just $(a,b,c,d)$ and I represent them as a column vector. For example, the coefficients of $i$ are $(0,1,0,0)$)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! If you post this as an answer, I'd accept it.

Comment: I have to go now. If you got the point, you can answer yourself and accept your answer for future reference. Otherwise, I may put an answer in a few days. Good luck!

Answer (score 13):

I am not sure exactly what you mean by asking "... why the ...". "Why" questions can be hard to answer satisfactory in math.

The claim is that the Quaternions $\mathbb{H}$ are isomorphic (as $\mathbb{R}$-algebras) to the given set of matrices. The isomorphism looks like this:

$$
\phi: a + bi + cj + dk \longmapsto \begin{pmatrix}a & b & c & d  \\  -b & a & -d & c \\ -c &d &a& - b\\ -d& -c & b& a\end{pmatrix}.
$$
To "understand" why this is true, you "simply" check that this is an isomorphism.

You check for example that $\phi$ is bijective, which is clear from the construction.

Then you check that $\phi$ is an algebra homomorphism, so you need for $x,y\in \mathbb{H}$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$:

1. $\phi(xy) = \phi(x)\phi(y)$ for $x,y\in\mathbb{H}$
2. $\phi(x+y) = \phi(x) + \phi(y)$
3. $\phi(\lambda x) = \lambda\phi(x)$

The last two are not difficult to check. The first one requires a bit of work.

Even though this does not answer the minus signs are where there are in the matrix, I highly recommend that you try to prove that $\phi$ is a homomorphism. This exercise will make you more familiar with the Quaternions.

But note if you check property $3$ above you would need (as a special case)
$$
\phi((bi)(bi))  = \phi(ib)\phi(ib).
$$
That is you would need
$$
\begin{pmatrix} -b^2 & 0 & 0& 0  \\  0 & -b^2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 &0 &-b^2& 0\\ 0& 0 & 0& -b^2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & b & 0& 0  \\  -b & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 &0 &0& -b\\ 0& 0 & b& 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & b & 0& 0  \\  -b & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 &0 &0& -b\\ 0& 0 & b& 0\end{pmatrix}.
$$
So here you can see that you "need" the minus on all the $b$'s. In this case it comes down to the fact that $i^2 = -1$.

Comment: The question asks about the real matrix representation; not the complex matrix representation. And by "why", I mean to say that surely that 4x4 matrix wasn't constructed accidentally. What is the logic behind its construction? Why are the minus signs and letters $a,b,c,d$ placed where they are?

Comment: @chubbycantorset: I updated my answer. Does it help now?

Comment: Not exactly. I've checked those things before, but my question asks how the map was constructed as such. To make an analogy, **perhaps** the formula to add the first $n$ digits was created by "experimental observation," so to say. Maybe someone just looked at the sequence of sums, and found a pattern to deduce that it should be $n(n+1)/2$. I'm looking for a similar explanation here, since I can't see how you can "experimentally observe" that this has to be the matrix for the quaternions.

Comment: @chubbycantorset: So you are asking for how people historically came up with the representation?

Comment: How they *may* have come up with it. Not necessarily how they did it exactly. I want to know if observing some property of the Quarternions can lead one to deduce that this should be the representation matrix. Although the placement of the minus signs on $b$ does help somewhat understand what's going on.

Comment: @chubbycantorset: I don't know how people can up with the representation. You could try to search through academic papers. But maybe someone was just sitting and trying to represent the Quaternions as matrices. Having experience with $2\times 2$ matrices gives you ideas on how larger matrices work and then it might not take that long to simply guess.

Comment: Hello @Thomas, do you happen to know why this doesn't work anymore for dimensions bigger than $1$? I asked this question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1029099/one-more-question-about-mapping-quaternionic-matrices-into-real-matrices).

Comment: There is a unique dictionary between the real and the complex representations: a complex number $a+bi$ can be regarded as a matrix $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ -b & a \end{pmatrix}.$ For $M \in \text{Mat}_n(\mathbb{C})$ replacing each entry $z$ with a $2\times2$ block $\begin{pmatrix} \text{re}z& \text{im}z \\ -\text{im}z & \text{re}z \end{pmatrix}$ gives a real $2n \times 2n$ matrix.

Answer (score 4):

It is a simple consequence of the multiplication rules of the quaternions.

So
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left( {a + bi + cj + dk} \right) \cdot 1 = \left( {\matrix{
   a & b & c & d  \cr 
   { - b} & a & { - d} & c  \cr 
   { - c} & d & a & { - b}  \cr 
   { - d} & { - c} & b & a  \cr 
 } } \right)^{\,T} \left( {\matrix{
   1  \cr 
   0  \cr 
   0  \cr 
   0  \cr 
 } } \right) = \left( {\matrix{
   1  \cr 
   0  \cr 
   0  \cr 
   0  \cr 
 } } \right)^{\,T} \left( {\matrix{
   a & b & c & d  \cr 
   { - b} & a & { - d} & c  \cr 
   { - c} & d & a & { - b}  \cr 
   { - d} & { - c} & b & a  \cr 
 } } \right) = \left( {\matrix{
   a  \cr 
   b  \cr 
   c  \cr 
   d  \cr 
 } } \right)  \cr 
  & \left( {a + bi + cj + dk} \right) \cdot i = \left( {\matrix{
   a & b & c & d  \cr 
   { - b} & a & { - d} & c  \cr 
   { - c} & d & a & { - b}  \cr 
   { - d} & { - c} & b & a  \cr 
 } } \right)^{\,T} \left( {\matrix{
   0  \cr 
   1  \cr 
   0  \cr 
   0  \cr 
 } } \right) = \left( {\matrix{
   { - b}  \cr 
   a  \cr 
   { - d}  \cr 
   c  \cr 
 } } \right) \cr} 
$$
and so on

Comment: @chubbycantorset: does this answer to your question?

Answer (score -1):

If It is not a misunderstanding, the question of "why as such (possible others?)" is equivalent to the problem of finding out ALL 4x4 real matrix representations of the Quaternions. The fact is: all those matrix representations are conjugated to each other. In other words, this is the only 4x4 real matrix representation of the Quaternions up to equivalent.