# One more question about mapping quaternionic matrices into real matrices

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, quaternions

Real matrices that lie in the image of the inclusion homomorphism $\rho_n: M_n(\mathbb C) \to M_{2n}(\mathbb R)$ are called complex linear real matrices. It is easy to see that a real matrix is complex linear if and only if it commutes with $I = \rho_n(iI)$.

In analogy to this I am now studying the quaternionic inclusion $M_n(\mathbb H) \to M_{4n}(\mathbb R)$ using the inclusion $\psi_n: M_n(\mathbb H) \to M_{2n}(\mathbb C)$. If $i,j,k$ denote the unit quaternions then I want to find matrices $I$ and $J$ such that a real matrix is quaternionic linear if and only if it commutes with $I$ and $J$.

In $1$ dimension I tried $I=\rho_{2n} \circ \psi_n (iI)$ and $J=\rho_{2n} \circ \psi_n (jI)$ but the problem then is that $I^2 \neq -1$ and $J^2 \neq -1$.

Why does $I=\rho_{2n} \circ \psi_n (iI), J=\rho_{2n} \circ \psi_n (jI)$ not work in the quaternionic case? Is there an insightful geometric (or other) explanation? For the inclusion of complex matrices into real matrices setting $J=\rho_{2n} (iI)$ worked.

**Edit** For a definition of $\rho_n$:

define $\rho_n : M^n(\mathbb C) \to M^{2n}(\mathbb R)$ as $A_{ij}\mapsto \begin{array}{cc} a_{ij} & b_{ij} \\ -b_{ij} & a_{ij} \end{array}$ if $A_{ij}=(a_{ij} + i b_{ij})$

and $\color{blue}{\psi_n}: M^n(\mathbb H) \to M^{2n}(\mathbb C)$ as $A_{ij}\mapsto \begin{array}{cc} a_{ij} & b_{ij} \\ -\overline{b_{ij}} & \overline{a_{ij}} \end{array}$ if $A_{ij}=(a_{ij} +  b_{ij}j)$

**Edit 2 (in response to the anwer)**

Let $$I = \rho(\color{blue}{\psi(i)})= \rho\left (
\begin{array}{cc} \color{blue}{i} & \color{blue}{0} \\ \color{blue}{0} & \color{blue}{-i} \end{array}\right)$$  Then 
$$ I = \left ( \begin{array}{cccc} 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{array} \right )$$

so that

$$  I^2 = -1$$

**Edit 3**

After the discussion with Incnis Mrsi I calculated $J^2=I^2 =-1$ for $J=\rho_{2}(\psi_1(j))$ and $I=\rho_{2}(\psi_1(i))$. I am confused that this seems to work. The reason why I asked this quetion is the following passage in [Tapp's matrix groups for undergraduates](http://books.google.com/books?id=Un_15Im3NhUC&printsec=frontcover&hl=ja#v=onepage&q&f=false):

[image]

In particular,

> why is $I\neq\rho_{2n}(\psi_n(i))$ and $J\neq\rho_{2n}(\psi_n(j))$ for
>   $n>1$? (for $n=1$, apparently it works as I just verified).

Comment: can you specify how are defined the homomorphisms $\rho_n$, $\psi_n$, $\rho_{2n}$ ?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Not mine. I'm working on your question, but I don't well understand the problem. It seems to me that all is OK. Your problem is to find the matrices $I_{4n}$ and $J_{4n}$ ?

Comment: I've not the book, so in the commutative diagrams, what means $R_{J_{4n}}$ ?

Comment: $R_A$ is used to denote the linear map corresponding to the matrix $A$ (if given in the standard basis): $R_A(X) = (X^TA)^T$ where $^T$ denotes the transpose. The paragraph I included in the question gives $I_{4n}$ and $J_{4n}$ so I just want to know why $I_{4n}=\rho_{2n}(\psi_n(i))$ and $J_{4n}=\rho_{2n}(\psi_n(i))$ is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if your representation of quaternionic matrices gives $I^2≠−1$, it indicates you made a mistake and need to check which 4 × 4 real (or 2 × 2 complex) blocks do you use. You can consult [this Wikipedia discussion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/talk:Classical_group#Matrix_groups_over_non-commutative_rings) for working examples (although there are *many* possible choices).

Second, your analogy between ℂ and ℍ is flawed because of poor algebraic design. Complex numbers form a *field*, that requires all element to commute, specifically
$$∀z∈ℂ: i\,z = z\,i\,,$$
that implies said commutation requirement for matrix representations.

The algebra of quaternions isn’t a (true) field, it is only a *skew field* (a division algebra). $i\,z = z\,i$ isn’t an identity anymore, it’s an equation of ℂ (a two-dimensional real subalgebra of ℍ). Consequently, real (or complex) representation of quaternions, or quaternionic matrices, will not generally commute with any of $I, J, K$. You have to use other kind of matrix equation, such as ones using complex conjugate transpose (look again at [the en.WP link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/talk:Classical_group#Matrix_groups_over_non-commutative_rings) for some insights).

Comment: What you state in your first paragraph is wrong. Please see the calculations, I added them to my question. I thoroughly checked them and could find no mistake.

Comment: @learner: really? I see no less than two. First, $i$ times identity matrix in Mat₂(ℂ) is $\begin{pmatrix}i&0\\0&i\end{pmatrix}$, not $\begin{pmatrix}0&i\\i&0\end{pmatrix}$. Second, neither of two results in $\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&1\\0&0&-1&0\\0&-1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$ in Mat₄(ℝ) for any reasonable choice of basis in ℂ²→ℝ⁴.

Comment: @learner: also, I suggest you to avoid statements like “what you state in your first paragraph is wrong” unless you are competent enough to understand and assess what does another party say and, preferably, point to apparent contradictions explicitly. IMHO here we don’t see such a case.

Comment: I said rubbish myself in the first comment. Of course, $I$ should not be $i$ times identity matrix, but $\begin{pmatrix}i&0\\0&-i\end{pmatrix}$ due to complex conjugation.

Comment: $$\left ( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & i \\ i & 0 \end{array}\right)$$
is not the identity matrix it is $\psi $ applied to $i \in \mathbb H$:
$$ \psi (i ) =\left ( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & i \\ i & 0 \end{array}\right)$$

I added color to the question to make it clearer.

Comment: $ψ(i) = \begin{pmatrix}i&0\\0&-i\end{pmatrix}$ follows from $i = i\cdot 1 + 0\cdot j$. Full stop.

Comment: Toatsmagoats, you are right. Thank you.

Comment: I did both calculations in $1$ dimension again and verified that indeed $I^2 = J^2 = -1$. The problem is: it is a comment in my book that this does not work. Is it a mistake in my book? (I am about take a screenshot and also link to the sentence.)

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with what you write in the second part of your answer. Maybe there are two ways to evade problems with the fact that $\mathbb H$ is only a skew-field: one is to use different equations that we want to hold in the real matrices and the other is to use different matrices for $I$ and $J$ so as to make $I^2 =J^2=-1$ and the other quaterion equations still hold?

Comment: And the paragraph in the book seems to contradict your last paragraph: the book suggests that indeed we can find real representations of $\mathfrak I := iI$ and $\mathfrak J := jI$ such that a real matrix $M$ is quaternionic linear if and only if $M\mathfrak J = \mathfrak J M$ and $M\mathfrak I = \mathfrak I M$. Or am I misunderstanding the section in the book which I included in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Since I've not the book cited in OP and I'm not sure to well understand the notation that was used, I begin by fixing notation.
We have two homomorphisms:
$$
\rho: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow M_2(\mathbb{R}) \qquad 
\rho(z)=\rho(a+ib)= 
\left[ 
 \begin{array}{ccccc}
a&b  \\
 -b &a
\end{array}
\right]
$$
and:
$$
\psi: \mathbb{H} \rightarrow M_2(\mathbb{C}) \qquad 
\psi(x)=\psi(x_0+\mathbf{i}x_1+ \mathbf{j}x_2+\mathbf{k}x_3)= 
\left[ 
 \begin{array}{ccccc}
x_0+ix_1&x_2 +ix_3 \\
 -x_2+ix_3 &x_0-ix_1
\end{array}
\right] = X_{(2)}
$$
that are homomorphisms between rings, so that:
$$
\rho(wz)=\rho(w)\rho(z) \qquad \psi(xy)=\psi(x)\psi(y)
$$
(Note that in second case the order is important because $\mathbb{H}$ is a noncommutative ring.)

We can genaralize $\rho$ as:
$$
\rho_2: M_2(\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow M_4(\mathbb{R}) 
$$
$$
\rho_2(A) =
\rho_2 \left( 
\left[ 
 \begin{array}{ccccc}
z_{1,1}&z_{1,2}  \\
 z_{2,1} &z_{2,2}
\end{array}
\right]
\right) =
\left[ 
 \begin{array}{ccccc}
\rho(z_{1,1})&\rho(z_{1,2})  \\
\rho( z_{2,1}) &\rho(z_{2,2})
\end{array}
\right]
$$
and more general:
$$
\rho_n: M_n(\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow M_{2n}(\mathbb{R})
$$
$$
\rho_n(A) =
\rho_n \left( 
\left[ 
 \begin{array}{ccccc}
z_{1,1}& \cdots &z_{1,n}  \\
\cdots \\
 z_{n,1} & \cdots &z_{n,n}
\end{array}
\right]
\right)
=\left[ 
 \begin{array}{ccccc}
\rho(z_{1,1})&\cdots &\rho(z_{1,n})  \\
\cdots \\
\rho( z_{n,1})&\cdots &\rho(z_{2,n})
\end{array}
\right]
$$
and analogously we can do for $\psi$ to define $\psi_n$:

Now, working in n=1 for simplicity, we have the homomorphisms:
$$
\rho_2 \circ \psi : \mathbb{H} \rightarrow M_4(\mathbb{R}) 
$$
so defined:
$$
\begin{split}
\rho_2 \circ \psi(x)=\rho_2(\psi(x))=\rho_2(X_{(2)})  &= \\
= \left[ 
 \begin{array}{ccccc}
\rho(x_0+ix_1)&\rho(x_2 +ix_3) \\
\rho( -x_2+ix_3) &\rho(x_0-ix_1)
\end{array}
\right] &=\\
= \left[ 
 \begin{array}{ccccc}
x_0&x_1&x_2 &x_3 \\
-x_1&x_0&-x_3 &x_2 \\
-x_2&x_3&x_0 &-x_1 \\
-x_3&-x_2&x_1 &x_0 
\end{array}
\right] = X_{(4)}
\end{split}
$$
note that the rows of this matrix are the ordered quadruples of the components of the quaternionic vector
$$
\left[ 
 \begin{array}{ccccc}
1x \\
\mathbf{i}x\\
\mathbf{j}x \\
\mathbf{k}x 
\end{array}
\right] 
$$
so we adopt the useful notation:
$$
\rho_2 \circ \psi(x)=
\left[ \left[
 \begin{array}{ccccc}
1x \\
\mathbf{i}x\\
\mathbf{j}x \\
\mathbf{k}x 
\end{array}
\right] \right]
$$
now it's easy to see that
$$
\rho_2 \circ \psi(\mathbf{i})=I_{(4)}=
\left[ 
\left[ 
 \begin{array}{ccccc}
\mathbf{i} \\
-1\\
-\mathbf{k} \\
\mathbf{j} 
\end{array}
\right] \right] =
\left[
 \begin{array}{ccccc}
0&1&0 &0 \\
-1&0&0 &0 \\
0&0&0 &-1 \\
0&0&1 &0 
\end{array}
 \right]
$$
as in OP and, in the same way, we can find $J_{(4)}=\rho_2 \circ \psi(\mathbf{j})$ and $K_{(4)}=\rho_2 \circ \psi(\mathbf{k})$.

And, more important, we easily see that
$$
\rho_2 \circ \psi(\mathbf{i}x)=
\left[ \left[
 \begin{array}{ccccc}
1\mathbf{i}x \\
\mathbf{i}\mathbf{i}x\\
\mathbf{j}\mathbf{i}x \\
\mathbf{k}\mathbf{i}x 
\end{array}
\right] \right]=
\left[ \left[
 \begin{array}{ccccc}
\mathbf{i}x \\
-x\\
-\mathbf{k}x \\
\mathbf{j}x 
\end{array}
\right] \right]
$$
is different from
$$
\mathbf{i} \left(\rho_2 \circ \psi(x)\right)=
\mathbf{i}
\left[ \left[
 \begin{array}{ccccc}
1x \\
\mathbf{i}x\\
\mathbf{j}x \\
\mathbf{k}x 
\end{array}
\right] \right]=
\left[ \left[
 \begin{array}{ccccc}
\mathbf{i}x \\
-x\\
\mathbf{k}x \\
-\mathbf{j}x 
\end{array}
\right] \right]
$$
but we have:
$$
\rho_2 \circ \psi(\mathbf{i}x)=\rho_2\left[\psi(\mathbf{i})\psi(x)\right]=\rho_2\left(\psi(\mathbf{i})\right)\rho_2\left(\psi(x)\right)
$$
so that the diagram in OP commutes if we take, on the right side, $I_{(4)}=\rho_2\left(\psi(\mathbf{i})\right)$.
I think that, with a bit of work, we can extend this reasoning to the case $n>1$.

I hope this can be an answer to the question. I'm not sure in my understanding of the page of the book, but I suspect that there is a mistake in the matrices named $\mathcal{I}_4$ and $\mathcal{J}_4$.